tail call optimization with arguments on stack and callee with more arguments than caller
I have been writing a compiler and have discussed this situation with a colleague.
In the most general case, suppose you have your arguments on the stack (once argument registers are exhausted).
If tail recursion:

simply overwrite the stack arguments, perform the appropriate bookkeeping, and make the call

Otherwise:

if the callee has less arguments than the caller, simply overwrite the first K, and do the same

Question:

if the callee has more arguments, what do you do?

Here's a picture representation:
A's frame
....
arg2 of B
arg1 of B
_______
B's frame

and now B wants to call C and do TCO, but C has 3 arguments, what do you do?
One solution is to make a minimal frame just responsible for handling this control and placing the arguments; however, that seems like it defeats the purpose of TCO.
My colleague says that it is impossible to perform TCO in this case.

Depends on who is removing the arguments and whether your architecture uses the stack for return address.

I'm mostly curious about a caller-cleanup convention. I guess with callee-cleanup, the problem becomes a bit trivial. @Jester I'm still not certain what stack for return address has to do with things


One solution is to make a minimal frame just responsible for handling this control and placing the arguments; however, that seems like it defeats the purpose of TCO.

I would agree with you that it does defeat the ideas of TCO.

However, if the compiler has access to the code of the method body for the callee, there are some other options, just like inlining is an option though only when the compiler has that (access to the code of the method body for the callee).
With access to the method body of the callee (yet without necessarily inlining), then the compiler can duplicate the method customized for this call site situation — here, a version of the same method body that removes one "extra" argument before returning.  Could be kind of clunky depending on the calling convention (and possibly on linker support to eliminate code duplication), but not necessarily totally impossible.

This kind of method duplication (of the generated code, customized for some purpose) is sometimes performed for generic parameters, such as in C# when the compiler customizes the generated method body based on particular choices for the generic parameters such as primitive types (int, float) vs. objects.

Still, as you've already noticed, register-heavy ISAs with their register-heavy calling conventions offer more and simpler opportunities for TCO than stack-based calling conventions.

It is theoretically possible, and can sometimes be seen in some hand-written assembly thunks. Let's make your example more concrete:
int C(int a, int b, int c);
int B(int a, int b)
{
   return C(a, b, a + b);

and let's assume this is x86 cdecl so all parameters are stack based. Then B may look something like:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, [ebp + 8]
add eax, [ebp + 12]
pop ebp
; right now stack looks like: [retaddr] [a] [b]
xchg eax, [esp + 8] ; [retaddr] [a] [a+b], eax=b
xchg eax, [esp + 4] ; [retaddr] [b] [a+b], eax=a
xchg eax, [esp] ; [a] [b] [a+b], eax=retaddr
push eax ; [retaddr] [a] [b] [a+b]
jmp C

Or some similar way to reformat the stack as required. You could add arguments, remove arguments, change their order etc. I don't know of any compiler that could do such a thing, though. This is not impossible but I guess considered impractical.
EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, TCO with different argument frame size cannot be done in caller-cleanup calling conventions (so most of them). Also I just remembered some calling conventions, notably x86-64, require a particular stack alignment which may impose additional troubles with TCO.

Except B's caller will only remove 2 arguments so the stack will be unbalanced. This could work for callee cleanup (stdcall).

Note that moving the return address will not work on systems that use shadow stacks.

@RaymondChen I thought shadows stacks implementations would only validate the return address itself and not its location in "normal" stack? Wouldn't matter where it was read from, as long as correct address has been read, no?

One implementation of shadow stacks is to create a second stack running in parallel to the CPU stack. Let N = (base address of shadow stack) - (base address of CPU stack). A call instruction decrements rsp, and then writes the return address to rsp and rsp+N. A ret instruction reads the return address from rsp and compares it to the return address in rsp+N. If you move the return address on the stack, then rsp will have a different value when the ret instruction is executed, and the value at rsp+N will not match.

Other processors (e.g. arm64) use pointer authentication: Before saving the return address on the stack, hash it with the current stack pointer address and some other secret data, and save that information with the return address. When returning, recalculate the hash and crash if it doesn't match. If you change the stack pointer, then the hash will not match.

@RaymondChen thank you for the explanation. Indeed such implementations would break this technique. Guess I have some reading to do (and also it is time to forget such idioms as jump via push/ret and PC reading via call/pop)

Yea, I’d asked this question with a calling convention in mind, as I was curious how a compiler might routinely handle this situation.

If you care about efficiency, also keep in mind that xchg with a memory operand has an implicit lock prefix since 386, so that's an extremely inefficient way to shift 12 bytes up or down.  Stuff like push/ret instead of jmp will also unbalance the return-address predictor which assumes that calls match with rets, leading to branch mispredicts for future ret instructions.
